# ResolveEventHandler only called once, succeed or fail

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-assembly

I am working on a solution that has a set up like this: We have assembly A which performs some functions, and assembly B which is purely domain models that are used by assembly A (and other assemblies). Both are stored in Azure and are downloaded for use when required by the solution.

Assembly A is downloaded and loaded fine, and I have created a ResolveEventHandler to ensure that Assembly B is downloaded when required and I've added it by doing:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(AssemblyResolveFunc);
```

The resolver works fine but the issue is it is only called once, regardless of the outcome. If Assembly B is found then it loads it and all is well, however if Assembly B has not yet been uploaded and can't be found then it fails as expected, but it will never try again. On the next call it will simply throw an error and will not try to resolve the dependency.

I feel like I'm not understanding the way ResolveEventHandlers are meant to be used, but until assembly B is loaded correctly, should it not retry each time?

Comment: What's the error that it throws?

Comment: That's very strange too, it throws a custom exception with the message "Failed to resolve assembly dependencies", of which the only place that exception is thrown is in the AssemblyResolveFunc, despite the fact that it never seems to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have only got a single change resolving assemblies. This operation is quite expensive, so it won't try it over and over again.

What might help is to manually walk down the [referenced assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx) and download and load those assemblies manually afterwards.

Comment: I actually tried this. I manually check the loaded assemblies and required assemblies to check which need to be loaded. Then I call the resolve function manually, it SUCCEEDS and downloads and loads the dependency and I can even see that it is loaded in when I look at AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(), and yet it still throws an error when trying to use Assembly A.

Comment: Okay. Can you give a code sample? This might be a more specific problem.

Comment: After reading some documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx , Step 2 in particular), it seems to suggest that if I add <disableCachingBindingFailures enabled="1" /> to my app.config it will not cache the failure and should try to resolve it each time (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404312(v=vs.110).aspx), however after adding it it does not seem to work. It is also not suggested by intellisense which makes me wonder if I am putting it in the right place / it even exists any more.